# 500 internal server error issue with opening files

Tags: python, apache2

I get a `500 internal server error` every time I try to open up a text or `csv database` file using my python `cgi script`. The codes I've tried to run are:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if form.getvalue("name"):
    f = open('CartEdit.csv', 'w')
    f.truncate()

with open('Cart.csv', 'rb') as inp:
  with open('CartEdit.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if row[0] != "0":
            writer.writerow(row)
```

These codes work perfectly, if I run them locally. I have checked the server logs and it just told me that these codes are the problem. Any suggestions or anybody with the same problem who can pass me advice will be greatly appreciated. I'm running this on an apache2 web server.

Comment: First, please fix the indentation in your Python code.  Several lines are indented with two spaces instead of four.  Having incorrect indentation in Python can cause headaches in debugging.  Second, please include the error you are experiencing in the logs running your code on the server.  Since there is no error handling in the above code, is it possible that the files you're reading don't exist, or the files you're trying to write to aren't accessible to your user running the app on the server?